# Finding duplicates with the same values MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a data set that I want to find the duplicates with the same values in multiple rows. For instance I have a data set that contains 12 different rows and I know the bottom 2 rows have similar values besides the _id and title values. How do I query to find these results? As if i dont already know these are duplicates.
My collection is 'sales'

```json
[
  {
    _id: "C12",
    title: "blouse",
    price: 15,
    units_sold: 100,
    retail_price: 30,
    ad_boost: 1,
    rate_count: 34,
    rating: 4
  },
  {
    _id: "C10",
    title: "loose floral blouse",
    price: 15,
    units_sold: 100,
    retail_price: 30,
    ad_boost: 1,
    rate_count: 34,
    rating: 4
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `$group` by all the fields that you identify as duplicate check key. You can `$push` the `_id` into an array for later fetching/processing.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        price: "$price",
        units_sold: "$units_sold",
        retail_price: "$retail_price",
        ad_boost: "$ad_boost",
        rate_count: "$rate_count",
        rating: "$rating"
      },
      duplicate_ids: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$_id",
          title: "$title"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/x3T8nu7Mmzv) for your reference.